# Unity can't rotate particle system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using the oneShot Explosion_1 from this asset:

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/vfx/particles/particle-effects-1-90769

I want to rotate it by 90° on the x-axis, but if i change the rotation of the object, or its parent object it has no effect on this particle system.

What i tried yet:

- disabling `velocity over lifetime`
- changing the `simulation space` to `world`
- try to rotate the `gameobject` with the `particle system`
- add the `gameobject` with the `particle system` to a `parent object` and try to `rotate` that `gameobject`.
- change the `3D Start Rotation.`

Comment: what version of Unity are you using?

Comment: Unity 2018.1.0f2.

Comment: I tried with Unity 2018.2. but didn't work either

Answer (score 1):

@Noblight is on the right track:

Depending on which shape you select, the particles should always fire the way the transform is pointing. Sphere is always 360, hemisphere is always within 90 degrees of forwards, cone always aims the way the transform goes.

Now, down in ForceOverLifeTime and VelocityOverLifetime, the settings for Local/Global really do pick which coord system to use. But not many people use those. For example, "thruster flames" are easy to make with a tight cone and sizeOverTime.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Particles in hierarchy]

There are 4 particles in hierarchy. Every particle is actually rotated when the transform is rotated. But a particle has its own shape which determines the shape of it.
[image: Particle shape]

The explode blow can be changed by modifying the gravity modifier value. Here is the result : [image: explosion getting down]

A way to make this particle looks rotated is by altering `Velocity over Lifetime` the value in `explode_blow` particle. Here's the image :
[image: Velocity over Lifetime in explode_blow particle]

Comment: thanks for the info, but making it blow horizontally is what i would need :/

Comment: @AlpakaJoe I have added a new probable way